# Problems with Hilt DI

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

Sorry for seally question, I have never used Dagger/Hilt before. Can't understand how to inject dependencies in my app. Here is what have now:

```
@InstallIn(Application::class)
@Module
abstract class RepositoryModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindProductRepository(productRepository: ProductRepository): IProductRepository

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindCategoryStorage(categoryStorage: CategoryStorageImpl) : CategoryStorage

    companion object {
        @Provides
        @Singleton
        fun createRoomDataBase(@ApplicationContext context: Context) : ProductRoomDatabase = ProductRoomDatabase.getDatabase(context)

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        fun createProductDao(productRoomDatabase: ProductRoomDatabase) = productRoomDatabase.productDao()

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        fun createCategoryDao(productRoomDatabase: ProductRoomDatabase) = productRoomDatabase.categoryDao()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hilt comes with three pre-made components:

`ApplicationComponent | SingletonComponent` - component that contains application-level dependencies and live until application lives.

`ActivityComponent` - component that contains `Activity`-level dependencies

`FragmentComponent` - component that contains `Fragment` level dependencies

`InstallIn` annotation suggests that all dependendencies in the current module will be available in the argument of the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

There are many courses and tutorials about this topic, but most of them just rephrase the original documentation. I would strongly suggest you read this documentation, from official Android website
https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android